# Prove that $\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_k}}{3^k+1}\:$ is convergence sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_k}}{3^k+1}\:$ is convergence sequence

$b_n \in \mathbb{N}$

I need to prove it by Cauchy's convergence test :

so let $\epsilon > 0 $ I need to fine $N$ such that for every $n>N$ and for every $p \in \mathbb{N}$ :

$|a_{n+p}-a_n| < \epsilon$

$|\sum _{k=1}^{n+p}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_k}}{3^k+1}\: - \sum _{k=1}^n\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_k}}{3^k+1}\:| = |\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_{n+1}}}{3^{n+1}+1}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_{n+2}}}{3^{n+2}+1}+...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{b_{n+p}}}{3^{n+p}+1}|$

can any one help me how to continue from here ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried the triangle inequality?

Comment: Note that $\frac{(-1)^{b_j}}{3^j+1}<\frac{1}{3^j}$